# Splitting up a Spring Controller by mapping a sub-path to a different controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to split up a spring controller that has become rather bloated.  The main controller, FooController, is mapped to "/foo".  As FooController has grown, several handlers to the sub mapping "/foo/bar/" have emerged.  It feels like these "/foo/bar" calls should be handled by a different controller because of all the features being added.

I am using spring 4 and here's a code example of what I am trying to do:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/foo/")
public class FooController { 
// ...
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/foo/bar"")
public class BarController {
// ...
}
```

I am not able to receive requests to /foo/bar/.  Is this not possible with spring, or I am missing something?

I have set up the spring-servlet to be able to scan the BarController.

Because of backwards compatability issues with mobile clients, I am not able to simply add a BarController mapped to "bar/".  I can of course do so with future APIs, but I'd love to group all the APIs together if possible.

Comment: Can you add your request mappings from the web.xml to your code above?

Answer (score -1):

You can have nested URL's in the same FooController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/foo")
public class FooController { 

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/bar"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView someOperation(....){

    }
}
```